# Как правильно работать со значением по умолчанию при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Решил поработать на чистом `JS`, и возник банальный вопрос, который не могу понять как решить:

Есть две функции, одна открывает, вторая закрывает Боковое меню:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").className += ' mySidenavOpen';
    document.getElementById("opener").style.display = "none";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove("mySidenavOpen");
    document.getElementById("opener").style.display = "block";
}
```

И тут столкнулся с тем, что после того, как я открыл меню, и перехожу на другую страницу (обычный сайт с шаблонами, не SPA), то, естественно, меню по умолчанию закрыто, для чего решил юзать куки:

Изменил функцию открытия меню, описанную выше, добавив в неё сэт куки:

```
function openNav() {
    ...
    Cookies.set('mySidenav', 'open');
}
```

И перед всем этим делом, проверяю, есть ли в куках значение:

```
if (Cookies.get('mySidenav')) {
    if (Cookies.get('mySidenav') === 'open') {
        openNav();
    }
}
```

И теперь, что очевидно, при каждой загрузке страницы, меню открывается, но только после загрузки всего `JS`, при этом не являясь открытым по умолчанию (при рендеринге HTML).

Подскажите, как реализовать это правильно?

Если работать с `LocalStorage`, то суть не поменяется, ведь нужно, в любом случае, ждать, пока по ключу будет получено значение.

Думал про прелоадер, но дело в том, что страницы сейчас грузятся крайне быстро, в связи с малым весом статики и отсутствием медиа, и не хочется портить всё это впечатление бросающейся в глаза "подгрузкой" контента.

***ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ***

Куки получаю при помощи [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Все подключения `js` файлов идут перед закрывающимся тегом .

Ради решения этой задачи не хочу менять расположение скриптов.

Comment: Если правильно полян суть проблемы, могу посоветовать следующее: попробуйте на php дописать такую же проверку cookie, которая будет для, например, body добавлять класс, описывающий состояние страницы при открытом меню - тогда уже на момент генерации html меню будет открыто

Comment: @Cheg, а без PHP?

Comment: Что значит не остается открытым?

Comment: @Alex78191, конкретизировал.

Comment: Где ты проверяешь, есть ли в куках значение?

Comment: @Alex78191, кусок кода указал в примере. 
Расположение куска кода под футером.

Думаешь, следует расположить в хэде?

Comment: Расположи его до начала загрузки JS. Можешь скрипты через `defer` грузить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это да, вопрос задан 9 месяцев назад, и никто так и не ответил. Отвечу, лучше поздно, чем никогда )

Я сталкивался с такой проблемой, и решил ее вот так:

- Делаем для враппера (body) всего контента visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; transition: opacity .6s;
- на событие window on load врапперу добавляем класс .is-loaded котороый сделает visibility: visible; opacity: 1;

В итоге получаем на мгновение белый экран и быстрое плавное появление контента с работающими слайдерами, меню, селект2 и без дерганья. Очень приятно выглядит.